# Filtering a DataFrame for data of id's of which the values are decreasing over time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large time series dataset of patient results. A single patient has one ID with various result values. The data is sorted by date and ID. I want to look only at patients of which the values are strictly descending over time. For example patient x has result values 5, 3, 2, 1 would be true. However 5,3,6,7,1 would be false.

Example data:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(...)
print(df.head())
  PSA   PSAdate‎  PatientID    ...          datefirstinject  ADTkey  RT_PSAbin
0  2.40 2007-06-26      11448    ...      2006-08-05 00:00:00       1         14
1  0.04 2007-09-26      11448    ...      2006-08-05 00:00:00       1         15
2  2.30 2008-01-14      11448    ...      2006-08-05 00:00:00       1         17
3  4.03 2008-04-16      11448    ...      2006-08-05 00:00:00       1         18
4  6.70 2008-07-01      11448    ...      2006-08-05 00:00:00       1         19
```

So for this example, I want to only see lines with `PatientID`s for which the `PSA` Value is decreasing over time.

```
groupID = df.groupby('PatientID')
def is_desc(d):
    for i in range(len(d) - 1):
        if d[i] > d[i+1]:
            return False
    return True

x = groupID.PSA.apply(is_desc)
df['is_desc'] = groupID.PSA.transform(is_desc)
#patients whose PSA values is decreasing overtime.
df1 = df[df['is_desc']]
```

I get:

```
KeyError: 0
```

I suppose the loop cant make its way through the grouped values as it requires an array to find the 'range'. 
Any ideas for editing the loop?

Comment: And the question is..?

Comment: What do you mean by "unique id values"? Because I would think that means that this id only appears once, but then you say it's results should be descending, so that means it does appear multiple times... Maybe a very small example of possible data and expected output could help here.

Comment: @talz sorry it wasn't clear, I've updated the question. Same ID different result values per row. I've added in a very small snippet of PLENTY of rows & plenty of patients lol in the working dataset

Comment: thanks for including that data! But I do find it better to keep it simple, not include anything that is not relevant && necessary to the question (unnecessary columns, how you reed the data, etc.). Also, including an example for the expected output (or clearly and explicitly defining it) would help people give you solutions that perfectly match your problem. I wrote an answer, let me know if it helps.

Comment: Well, if you leave the function like I wrote it, you won't get this error... The `d` we are giving the function is a `Series` of `PSA` values for each group, so it's indexed with the original index from the `DataFrame`. So only one of the groups could have index `0`. If you don't understand what I'm saying, just change the loop back to how it is in the answer you copied it from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

```
# (see is_desc function definition below)
df['is_desc'] = df.groupby('PationtID').PSA.transform(is_desc)
df[df['is_desc']]
```

### Explanation

**Let's use a very simple data set:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,1,3,3,1], 'res': [3,1,2,1,5,1]})
```

It only contains the id and one value column (and it has an index automatically assigned from pandas).

So if you just want to get a list of all ids whose values are descending, we can group the values by the id, then check if the values in the group are descending, then filter the list for just ids with descending values.

So first let's define a function that checks if the values are descending:

```
def is_desc(d):
first = True
for i in d:
    if first:
        first = False
    else:
        if i >= last:
            return False
    last = i
return True
```

(yes, this could probably be done more elegantly, you can search online for a better implementation)

now we **group by the id**:

```
gb = df.groupby('id')
```

and **apply the function**:

```
x = gb.res.apply(is_desc)
```

`x` now holds this `Series`:

```
id
1     True
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool
```

so now if you want to filter this you can just do this:

```
x[x].index
```

which you can of course convert to a normal list like that:

```
list(x[x].index)
```

which would give you a list of all ids of which the values are descending. in this case:

```
[1, 2]
```

But if you want to also **have all the original data** for all those chosen ids do it like this:

```
df['is_desc'] = gb.res.transform(is_des)
```

so now df has all the original data it had in the beginning, plus a column that tell for each line if it's id's values are descending:

```
   id  res  is_desc
0   1    3     True
1   2    1     True
2   1    2     True
3   3    1    False
4   3    5    False
5   1    1     True
```

Now you can very easily filter this like that:

```
df[df['is_desc']]
```

which is:

```
   id  res  is_desc
0   1    3     True
1   2    1     True
2   1    2     True
5   1    1     True
```

Comment: this really helped, but I am getting false positives because the values are not linearly set like 5, 4, 3, 2, 1
more like 5, 2, 3, 5, 1
which gives a false positive with the function above.

Comment: Hey, @Ramy Saad I fixed the function. Take a look. And use it like it's here, not like what you edited into your question.

Comment: hey Talz, since you were so helpful with this question do you mind looking at a little more advanced question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51543616/finding-conditional-local-minima-values-in-time-series-python

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Selecting and sorting your data is quite easy and objective. However, deciding whether or not a patient's data is declining can be subjective, so it is best if you decide on a criteria beforehand to see if their data is declining.

To sort and select:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['pat_1', 10, 1],
        ['pat_1', 9, 2],
        ['pat_2', 11, 2],
        ['pat_1', 4, 5],
        ['pat_1', 2, 6],
        ['pat_2', 10, 1],
        ['pat_1', 7, 3],
        ['pat_1', 5, 4],        
        ['pat_2', 20, 3]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data).rename(columns={0:'Patient', 1:'Result', 2:'Day'})
print df

df_pat1 = df[df['Patient']=='pat_1']
print df_pat1

df_pat1_sorted = df_pat1.sort_values(['Day']).reset_index(drop=True)
print df_pat1_sorted
```

returns:

```
df:

  Patient  Result  Day
0   pat_1      10    1
1   pat_1       9    2
2   pat_2      11    2
3   pat_1       4    5
4   pat_1       2    6
5   pat_2      10    1
6   pat_1       7    3
7   pat_1       5    4
8   pat_2      20    3

df_pat1

  Patient  Result  Day
0   pat_1      10    1
1   pat_1       9    2
3   pat_1       4    5
4   pat_1       2    6
6   pat_1       7    3
7   pat_1       5    4

df_pat1_sorted

  Patient  Result  Day
0   pat_1      10    1
1   pat_1       9    2
2   pat_1       7    3
3   pat_1       5    4
4   pat_1       4    5
5   pat_1       2    6
```

For the purposes of this answer, I am going to say that if the first value of the new DataFrame is larger than the last, then their values are declining:

```
if df_pat1_sorted['Result'].values[0] > df_pat1_sorted['Result'].values[-1]:
print "Patient 1's values are declining"
```

This returns:

```
Patient 1's values are declining
```

There is a better way if you have many unique IDs (as I'm sure you do) of iterating through your patients. I shall present an example using integers, however you may need to use regex if your patient IDs include characters.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

min_ID = 1003
max_ID = 1005
patients = np.random.randint(min_ID, max_ID, size=10)
df = pd.DataFrame(patients).rename(columns={0:'Patients'})
print df

s = pd.Series(df['Patients']).unique()
print s

for i in range(len(s)):
    print df[df['Patients']==s[i]]
```

returns:

```
   Patients
0      1004
1      1004
2      1004
3      1003
4      1003
5      1003
6      1003
7      1004
8      1003
9      1003

[1004 1003] # s (the unique values in the df['Patients'])

   Patients
3      1003
4      1003
5      1003
6      1003
8      1003
9      1003

   Patients
0      1004
1      1004
2      1004
7      1004
```

I hope this has helped!

Comment: It sure did help, thank you for your detailed response. 

I do in fact have PLENTY of patient IDs (integers) and result values so how would i go about using your mid/max method ?

Comment: @RamySaad Please can you edit your question with the output of the `.head()` of your DataFrame, and also provide some examples of the values of the patient IDs, I can then try to help form an appropriate method of indexing the original DataFrame.

Comment: The methodology for iterating through your patient IDs is potentially subjective and is actually not related to DataFrames at all. For example if your IDs are of the form 0001, 0002, 0003 ..., then you can use something like `for i in [1, 2, 3, ...]: print int('000{}'.format(i))`. You have to also be aware of the datatypes of your patient IDs, if they are strings then you do not need the `int()` function etc.

Comment: You can also use make a list of unique patient IDs using `pd.Series(df).unique()` and iterate through this... I shall edit my answer to account for this

Comment: I've updated my question! I get a bunch of printed dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your question, interpreting 'decreasing' as monotonic decreasing:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {"PatientID": [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
     "PSAdate": [2010,2011,2012,2013,2010,2011,2012,2013],
     "PSA": [5,3,2,1,5,3,4,5]}

# Sorts by id and date
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d).sort_values(['PatientID', 'PSAdate'])

# Computes change and max(change) between sequential PSA's
df["change"] = df.groupby('PatientID')["PSA"].diff()
df["max_change"] = df.groupby('PatientID')['change'].transform('max')

# Considers only patients whose PSA are monotonic decreasing
df = df.loc[df["max_change"] <= 0]
```

```
print(df)

   PatientID  PSAdate  PSA  change  max_change
0          1     2010    5     NaN        -1.0
1          1     2011    3    -2.0        -1.0
2          1     2012    2    -1.0        -1.0
3          1     2013    1    -1.0        -1.0
```

**Note:** to consider only *strictly* monotonic decreasing PSA, change the final `loc` condition to `< 0`

Comment: This would return false positives. Taking only the first and last values of each ID assumes linearity in results, which is not true. For example, a single ID can have result values such as 5,3,7,9,3,2. 
though 5 is greater than 2, the values weren't strictly decreasing over time.

Comment: @RamySaad have changed to code to comply to the new logic.