# finding conditional local minima values in time series python

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, conditional-statements, minima

For a time series dataset:

A, How do I find the local minima (nadir values) for each ID? (local mins)

B, How do I find any subsequent values that are 2 greater than each local minima. (local mins + 2)

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2], 'value': [8,5,3,2,1,2,3,5, 1.5, 3, 1, 1.5, 2, 3, 4, 0.4]})
```

For A, I was able to use the following code to find all the nadir/local minimum values from the dataset, but they are not grouped by each id. How do I modify this to group them by id?

```
nadir_min = df.value[(df.value.shift(1) > df.value) & (df.value.shift(-1) > df.value)]
nadir_min
Out[1]: 
4     1.0
8     1.5
10    1.0
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

For B, I would like to get back the subsequent values after the nadir/local minimums that are two greater than the nadir/local minimums. For the example data above I would get back:

```
index  id value 
 6      1   3.0
 13     2   3.0
 14     2   4.0
```

Perhaps a conditional loop would do the trick as it can store each local min and compare the subsequent values if they are 2 greater than it. However, the working dataset is MASSIVE and would take too long to run so I am trying something like this:

```
df['min_plus2'] = (df['value'] >= nadir_min + 2) & (df.index > nadir_min_index)
```

Answer (score 1):

You do it with next code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2], 'value': [8,5,3,2,1,2,3,5, 1.5, 3, 1, 1.5, 2, 3, 4, 0.4]})    
df['loc_min'] = df.value[(df.value.shift(1) > df.value) & (df.value.shift(-1) > df.value)]
df['if_A'] = np.where(df['loc_min'].isna(), False, True)    
df['loc_min'].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)    
df['if_B'] = np.where(df['value'] - df['loc_min'] >= 2, True, False)
```

Answer for A:

```
df[df['if_A']==True]
```

Answer for B:

```
df[df['if_B']==True]
```

Comment: Hi Sergei, thank you for this solution, it is very close to what I am looking for, but it includes false positives for 'if_B'. I want only those values( =>2) that are AFTER the local minimum points in the dataset. This method includes the values that match the criteria that come before and after the minimum value. Have any ideas how to account for this ?

Comment: if_B shows only values larger then previous local min by at least 2 (Values AFTER local min).
row 6 - value 3 larger then prev local min from row 4
row 7 - value 5 larger then prev local min from row 4
row 13 - value 3 larger then prev local min from row 10
row 14 - value 4 larger then prev local min from row 10

Comment: Or I'm not getting what you need!

Comment: the first local min for id 2 is row 8 (value =1.5), so though row 7 is at least 2 greater than min value of row 8, row 7 comes BEFORE row 8. for id 2 only row 13 and 14 should be true. 
thank you for your patience, i hope this provides more clarity on what i need.

Comment: the issue i found is that the ids are not grouped by a function like groupby  so what ends up happening is row 7 is being compared with 1 and not nan like row 1, 2 and 3, which is a false positive.